# Cocos2d and iPhone 5 Retina Support?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, retina-display

I would like to know how to include retina images for the iPhone 5 in cocos2d. I already have large images from the iPad version of the game. How do I do that ? Unfortunately there is not very much information on the internet, so I thought I'll ask here. I do not have a working iPhone version of the game yet.

Comment: There is no ordinary version in iPhone 5. iPhone 5 have retina by default.

Comment: Yeah I actually mean different iPhone versions. So,basically that I could make out which device is used and accordingly use high-res images...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is built into cocos2d. Use xxx.png for standard resolution image, then provide a xxx-hd.png image and cocos2d will use that high-res version on Retina devices (including iPhone 5).

The file suffixes for iPad are -ipad and -ipadhd for Retina iPads.

Comment: really ? Wow, awesome, I expected it not to work... I'll try that and if this works, you'll be my hero :).

Comment: I'm afraid your solution does not work. The default image with the new cocos2d template is the only thing that works for now, so I'll have to write my own code to implement the usage of retina iphone images